# How to get the next item in an array using for (let obj of objects)

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

How can I get the next item in an array when iterating?

```
for (let item of list) {
  // item @ index + 1
}
```

I know I could use the loop with this syntax but prefer the previous one.

```
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop does not offer any syntax to do this, but you can combine the destructuring syntax introduced in ES6 with calling the entries() method on the array:

```
for (const [i, v] of ['a', 'b', 'c'].entries()) {
  console.log(i, v)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best example you can refer

```
let list = [4, 5, 6];

for (let i in list) {
    console.log(i); // "0", "1", "2",
}

for (let i of list) {
    console.log(i); // "4", "5", "6"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `in` to get the index:

```
for (let index in list) {
  // Use index
}
```

Or use `forEach`:

```
list.forEach((item, index) => {...});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to iterate the keys of the list via `for(..in..)` and, per-iteration, add one to the current index to obtain the index of the `next` value from the current iteration like so:

```js
let list = [4, 5, 6];

for (let i in list) {

  const next = list[Number.parseInt(i) + 1];

  console.log('curr=', list[i]);
  console.log('next=', next);
  console.log('---');
}
```

Some points to consider with this are:

- the last `next` value will be undefined
- this approach only works for arrays where values are accessed via integer indices
- the index of `i` needs to be parsed to an interger to ensure that the "add one" step returns the index of the next value (rather than a string concatenation)